# Kendo grid paging throwing an java script error kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js file

Tags: kendo-grid

I am currently working on Kendo Grid.
I have implemented ajax binding with default paging.

In ie10 i am getting a javascript error in aspnetmvc.min.js file before the pageload.
once page loaded everything is working perfectly.

below is the code i have used

```
.cshtml
--------
<div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIAjaxBinding.Model.PM_ANO>()

  .Name("grid")
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 

              .Ajax() 

              .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")

              .Data("productsReadData")
              )
           )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(anomaly => anomaly.GOD);
      columns.Bound(anomaly => anomaly.VER);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(anomaly => anomaly.C_ANO);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property
      columns.Bound(anomaly => anomaly.Y_ANO);
      // Create a column bound to the UnitsInStock property
      columns.Bound(anomaly => anomaly.Z_REP_AUTO);
  })
  .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(true)) // Enable paging
  .Sortable() // Enable sorting
 )
 </div>



in Layout page i have rendered like this
----------------------------------------
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

</head>

controller code
------------------
 public JsonResult  

 Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest                     request,            string    firstName, string lastName)
    {

        var _context = new E2A_GUIEntities();

        IQueryable<PM_ANO> anomaly = _context.PM_ANO;


            var total = anomaly.Count();

            if (request.Page > 0)
            {
                anomaly = anomaly.OrderBy(a => a.C_ANO).Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize);
            }
            anomaly = anomaly.Take(request.PageSize);
            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = anomaly, // Process data (paging and sorting applied)
                Total = total // Total number of records
            };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Please help me in resolving this problem.

THanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards,
Gangadhar

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 public JsonResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string firstName, string lastName)
        {

            var _context = new E2A_GUIEntities();

            IQueryable<PM_ANO> anomaly = _context.PM_ANO;


            //do any other logic here. 
            // eg  anomaly = anomaly.OrderBy(o => o.C_ANO).Where(w => w.D_ANO.Contains(firstname);



            return Json(anomaly.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Just make sure you have the following using statement included:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
```

The ToDataSourceResult extension method will do all the grid taking, paging, sorting, filtering and selection for you.

edit:

These are the files that I include as part of my Kendo Project

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.624/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.624/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.624/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js")"></script>
```

Obviously change the **2014.1.624** to the version you are using or the file path to match your project.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the optimized code. when i used this code i am getting the same javascript error. i don't know whether i am missing any javascript reference.

Comment: Have added the files that I use for my kendo projects. By the looks of it you are missing the all.min file which is probably where the error is being thrown from.